# Vanishing save files that both do and do not exist on hard drive for Mac, what is happening?

Tags: blend-files

I am using the latest version of Blender (2.90.1) on an iMac pro with Catalina 10.15.7. I'm working on a project and I save the file in a save folder i created under the file name "Relax.blend" all goes fairly well for a while and then one of the random times i figure i better save it there is a message in the blender info strip in red that says file type not supported, file saved with an "@" symbol. When i check my finder window for the save file there is only a file named "Relax.blend@" there for a save file. If i close and reopen blender and try and select the original "Relax.blend" save from the blender startup window it prompts with an unsupported file type and the option to select it again disappears (same goes for the drop down menu of opening recent files under the file menu once starting a new file; the option disappears) if I return to my finder window and attempt to remove the "@" and turn the extension into a .blend file it tells me there is already a file under this name. if i change the name to "Relax1.blend" it will then open properly again... then, sure enough, the same thing happens with the "Relax1.blend" file and again when i try "Relax2.blend". I have tried using search on my entire hard drive for any of the relax .blend files but they dont show up, and i can no longer name any files those names because they are already taken. so the computer both does and doesn't recognize the files existence; i cant name files the same name but also can't find the files to delete them. What the heck is going on!? Where are these files? at this rate im going to have 500 versions of the same file that i can't see using up space and names on my computer. does anyone have a solution or idea what is happening?

Comment: Is it just that file, or does it happen if you start a new (different) project and save that as well? What happens if you save it in a different folder?

Comment: i have tried saving it in a different location with no luck. I failed to mention i was using the sequence editor and using hundreds of stills; if that makes a difference. I have found out something new, but still no explanation why its happening. turns out the file folder containing all data for the .blend file has the .blend hidden somewhere within. when i delete the entire folder and its contents i am able to rename the .blend back to the original name. I cannot find the file anywhere within it and still can't reload it normally, but i can at least delete it.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. Unfortunately, I don't have a mac, so I'm unable to test anything. I was hoping it had something to do with that file itself, but based on your comment, it almost seems like it might have more to do with the filesystem. How does macOS hide files - is it possible some settings related to the folder are causing the save files to be hidden or otherwise restricted somehow ? Does @ mean anything specific with regards to Catalina file extensions, or is this the first time you've seen anything like it? Any chance you created the folder in a read-only partition?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, sort of. Blender version 3.0 seems to have resolved the issue. It no longer happens.